# error reporting: ROS_ERROR or error topic

Tags: ros, diagnostics, logging

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What is best practice for reporting global errors throughout ROS?

One option is to report errors through ROS_ERROR only.
A node could then subscribe to `/rosout_agg` to receive and parse the error messages.
The advantage would be that I get the topic and macros for free, and the messages even contain the posting node etc.
Disadvantage is that I need to discard a lot of messages with info level and debug level. And if I need things like an error code, I need to encode this in the log message text.

Another option is of course to create a dedicated topic for reporting errors and warnings. All nodes in the system then needs to publish to this topic.

Any advice appreciated, thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/278908/error-reporting:-ros_error-or-error-topic/) by [knxa](https://answers.ros.org/users/29756/knxa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 811 on 2018-01-05

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would actually use [`diagnostics`](http://wiki.ros.org/diagnostics) for this.
This is bascially an implementation of your second option with some additional sugar like analysis, aggregation and a viewer.

(All assuming "Reporting" means to send this to the user...)

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2018-01-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [knxa](https://answers.ros.org/users/29756/knxa/) on 2018-01-12**:
Thanks, I have come across diagnostics before, but have honestly been a bit confused about best practice.
For example [REP 107](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0107.html) states that is intended for reporting hardware data and errors.
I was looking for something that reports errors in general...

**Comment by [knxa](https://answers.ros.org/users/29756/knxa/) on 2018-01-12**:
... which might include that some user input was wrong, some file could not be found, etc.

**Comment by [knxa](https://answers.ros.org/users/29756/knxa/) on 2018-01-12**:
(As you state) it also seems Diagnostics is intended for user info. I was thinking that reported errors could also be used as input to an error handler. A global place that could be configured to take certain actions if certain errors occurs. But this seems like misuse of Diagnostics?

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2018-01-12**:
I agree about it being a misuse of diagnotics when using this for error handling in code.
I understand that diagnostics has been intended for HW mainly, but I think it is helpful in a lot of other places as well (as Long as it is about getting info to the user) (some might consider that misues too).

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2018-01-12**:
IMO, error handling should happen in the single nodes. So wrong user Input should be detected at the Moment of Input. Not existing files once you try to read/load them. And then the error should be produced in that node.

Maybe I am missing your Goal/idea why you want to have that centralized...

**Comment by [knxa](https://answers.ros.org/users/29756/knxa/) on 2018-01-12**:
I was imagining any error referring so a globally defined error code. A configuration could then specify various handlers for each error code. E.g. a node emits an error about low disk space or high temperature for X. An error handler node decides the appropriate action.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-01-12**:
These would seem to be largely application level and specific concerns, so creating an application specific implementation with topics and application-defined error codes with specific semantics seems justified.